# RShiny: Display a single table with multiple inputs using select box

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I have two sets of inputs: month(Jan ~ Dec), quarter(Q1 ~ Q4) and they are saved as dataframe in R environment. (12 months + 4 quarters, total 16 dataframes)

and I have created two select boxes that we can choose display months or quarters as picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9vUw.png)

but when I write two `output$table` code, shiny app is only reactive with either month output or quarter output.

I have successfully created two tables in single main panel.
However, rather than display two tables(looks ugly), I would like to display a single table in the main panel that reacting with both select box. (Two input and single output).

So what I have tried was write if statement, but it does not work.

Here are the server.R and ui.R I have been testing with

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
 sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose Month:", 
                  choices = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")),
      selectInput("dataset1", "Choose Quatar:", 
                  choices = c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"))
    ),  
    mainPanel(
DT::dataTableOutput("table") 
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  monthInput <- reactive({
    data = switch(input$dataset,
           "Jan" = Jan, "Feb" = Feb, "Mar" = Mar,
           "Apr" = Apr, "May" = May, "Jun" = Jun,
           "Jul" = Jul, "Aug" = Aug, "Sep" = Sep,
           "Oct" = Oct, "Nov" = Nov, "Dec" = Dec
           )
  })

    quatarInput <- reactive({
    data2 = switch(input$dataset,
           "Q1" = Q1, "Q2" = Q2, "Q3" = Q3, "Q4" = Q4
           )
  })


      #Test: Add if statement here -> If bla bla it is Month, else it is Quatar(Because both switch must work for same location where table is displayed)
    output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

      if (input$monthInput){
    DT::datatable(monthInput())
      } else {
        if(input$quatarInput){
    DT::datatable(quatarInput())}
      }

    })
    })

    shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

And one extra question is that is it possible to assign levels in select boxes?
For example, a high level select box has Month, or quarter, and when I choose Month, I can choose January to December in low level select box. In other words, when I choose quarter in high level select box, I can choose Q1 ~Q4 in the low level select box.

Could someone help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a suggestion for how to change your UI design.  Rather than having two selectInputs, have one selectInput that switches between the two styles (month and quarter) according to another input.

```
# I don't have your data, so here I'm just going to create some.  Delete these lines and replace them with your actual data
Jan = overflow::sorandf()
Feb = overflow::sorandf()
Mar = overflow::sorandf()
Apr = overflow::sorandf()
May = overflow::sorandf()
Jun = overflow::sorandf()
Jul = overflow::sorandf()
Aug = overflow::sorandf()
Sep = overflow::sorandf()
Oct = overflow::sorandf()
Nov = overflow::sorandf()
Dec = overflow::sorandf()
Q1 = overflow::sorandf()
Q2 = overflow::sorandf()
Q3 = overflow::sorandf()
Q4 = overflow::sorandf()


library(shiny)
library(DT)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      radioButtons("viewdataradio","View data by:", choices = c("month", "quarter"), inline = TRUE, selected = "month"),
      selectInput("dataset", "Choose Month:", 
                  choices = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))
    ),  
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput("table") 
    )
  )
))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  observe({
    if(input$viewdataradio == "month"){
      choices = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")
      firstchoice = "Jan"
      label = "Choose Month:"
    }else{
      choices = c("Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4")
      firstchoice = "Q1"
      label = "Choose Quarter:"
    }
    updateSelectInput(session, "dataset", label = label, choices = choices, selected = firstchoice)
  })

  data <- reactive({
    data = switch(input$dataset,
                  "Jan" = Jan, "Feb" = Feb, "Mar" = Mar,
                  "Apr" = Apr, "May" = May, "Jun" = Jun,
                  "Jul" = Jul, "Aug" = Aug, "Sep" = Sep,
                  "Oct" = Oct, "Nov" = Nov, "Dec" = Dec,
                  "Q1" = Q1, "Q2" = Q2, "Q3" = Q3, "Q4" = Q4
    )

  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(data())

  })
})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

This looks neater, and I think answers your question too.

Comment: This is what I was trying to figure out for past few days!. Thank you very very much!!